# How can I evaluate tars and gzips for validity without expanding them?

Tags: tar, compression, gzip, archive

LONG ago I wrote a backup script for our site and have updated it ever since. However, occasionally things go wrong and some of the older backups are now broken.

In days gone by I had used the utility `zipinfo` in our automated scripts to try and figure out if a previous backup was bad and then re-attempt a backup, but while we still have some `zip` laying around there are (at least) two issues.

First, `zip` has fundamental limitations and so we've used `tar` for larger backups.

And secondarily, `zip` doesn't capture as much metadata as `tar` does and so we prefer it for certain kinds of things.

Further, we've shifted to `gzip` instead of `zip`, and we're also compressing our `tars` as well...

Our backups are now huge and I'm trying to figure out what to remove and what to keep - no point in keeping broken files. So, I'm writing a script that merges our various backup directories - from on and off-site, etc - and I feel a serious need to check the validity of each file because sometimes one copy gets corrupted and the other is OK.

I did a look for a `gzip` version of `zipinfo` but didn't find it. And I've never heard of such a thing for `tar`, but I may just be ignorant!

I sure don't want to have to resort to expanding into disk space!

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like "tar -t" might be able to do this! ... A "not recoverable" error is one possible output from that command.

Comment: By the way, tar -t still decompresses the compressed archive, and tar still reads the whole of it, it's just that they skip the step where they're writing anything to disk

Comment: You should be storing cryptographic checksums with your backups to verify the archive integrity without needing to unpack it. This has the additional advantage that it will catch archive corruption that would be missed by `tar` (because `tar` doesn't perform any kind of data checksumming internally).

Comment: @larsks Thanks, larsks, ... could you expand a bit right here: "cryptographic checksums with your backups"? I'm well familiar with checksumming, but I'm not sure what you've got in mind here... Maybe you can share a link to something larger than a comment?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks, Markus, for the reminder about that. ... I'm more willing to suffer the read I/O than write. However, I note larsks' comment about tar not checksumming so maybe there could still be corruption?

Comment: @RichardT I used `par2` back when I backed up to CD-R and DVD-R media... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive

Comment: Yes absolutely. Tar, in all it's variants, is a really simplistic archive format and has no integrity control at all.

Comment: "Maybe you can share a link to something larger than a comment" This is a pretty common practice and you'll find many examples of it online. Briefly, when you create an archive, also store the checksum (e.g., `sha256sum backupfile.tar.gz > backupfile.tar.gz.sha256sum`). Then you can later re-compute the checksum for the tarfile and see if it matches your saved value. Alternately, investigate backup tools that do this for you automatically.

Comment: @larsks OH, THAT'S WHAT YOU MEANT?! Geez... I've been doing that for over 20 years... by changing the filename afterward so you can't lose it! However, WAY back when, we didn't have the higher quality ECC memory / cpu, etc, hardware and sometimes backups were defunct from the day you made them! :-( ...Today, of course, we're running some pretty good iron.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ...I note that with irony; I "grew up" with VMS Backup, and it DID have all sorts of techniques to catch errors and even repair / recover from many of them. ...It was said you had to have at least a two bit error in more than one place to have a not recoverable backup! But, I guess the Unix guys weren't as sophisticated as we Digital people were! ...But just look at DEC now! ;-)

Comment: @RichardT as a communications engineer, that just says it used a forward error correction code with minimum distance of 3 or more ;) not too exciting a code, your modern tape drive, hard drive, CD-ROM or flash memory has much mightier coding built in to the hardware!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding `gzip`:**

(This applies to `gz`, `tgz` and `tz` files.)

Noting that `zipinfo` is based on `unzip`, I investigated `gzip` more thoroughly and found that while there is no direct equivalent to `zipinfo -t`, there's a combination that works similarly with `gunzip`:

```
# gunzip -t -v [file-specification(s)]
[file-specification]: OK
```

Note, however, that the desired output is sent to `stderr` and not `stdout`! Further, there's a tab between the output colon and OK, so adjust scripting accordingly.

Regarding `tar`:

As noted in comments above, I similarly found that while tar doesn't have the checks we'd like, `tar -t` is a reasonable start at a "better than nothing" solution.

As with `gunzip`, the confirming output comes from `stderr`, not `stdout`, though both output streams can be / are useful, depending on your specific sub-goals.

Strictly speaking, the current version of tar from Fedora 38 complains with:

> This does not look like a tar archive

...if the archive is invalid. That is, just because there are no perceptible files in a tar doesn't mean it's necessarily invalid, it simply may have been improperly built in the first place. So, some might consider that an invalid archive! YMMV.